# How to select a subset of least resembling combinations of a common vector?

Tags: r, excel, combinations

I need to select 10 times different combinations of 15 items from a common set of 30 items, with several constraints.

First constraint: for each of the 10 combinations, I need to remove three items that should not be present in that specific combination. Let's say wf01, wf02 and wf03 for the first combination; wf04, wf05 and wf06 for the second combination and so on.

Second constraint: over the ten combinations, each item should be present the same number of times (5).

Third constraint: the ten combinations should be as different as possible from one another (i.e. they should avoid sharing common items as much as possible).

I am currently doing that in Excel, but I guess there should be a more efficient way in R!

Here is my coding so far:

```
# Data: 30 items (pictures to choose from)

PictureNames <- c("wf01", "wf02", "wf03", "wf04", "wf05", "wf06", "wf07", "wf08", "wf09", "wf10", "wf11", "wf12", "wf13", "wf14", "wf15", "wf16", "wf17", "wf18", "wf19", "wf20", "wf21", "wf22", "wf23", "wf24", "wf25", "wf26", "wf27", "wf28", "wf29", "wf30")

set.seed(10)

sample01 <- sample(PictureNames[4:30], 15)
sample02 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:3, 7:30)], 15)
sample03 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:6, 10:30)], 15)
sample04 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:9, 13:30)], 15)
sample05 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:12, 16:30)], 15)
sample06 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:15, 19:30)], 15)
sample07 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:18, 22:30)], 15)
sample08 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:21, 25:30)], 15)
sample09 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:24, 28:30)], 15)
sample10 <- sample(PictureNames[c(1:27)], 15)
```

Up to now, I implemented the constraints manually in Excel (I know…). First, I ensured that each item was present only 5 times across the 10 different combinations. Then, I created a matrix with the name of the picture as row and column. Each cell counted how many times a pair of pictures was present in the same combination across the 10 combinations. The value ranges from 0 (pictures never together) to 5 (pictures always together). Then, by manually shifting pictures between combinations, I managed to avoid the presence of 0s and 5s in this matrix. Afterwards, I implemented an optimisation task, where each picture should be associated with as many different pictures as possible, while respecting the previous constraints. To do so, for each picture I calculate the standard deviation of its column (or row) values. Then, I calculated the standard deviation of these standard deviations. Any shift that reduces this value while respecting the other constraints is retained. I managed to arrive to a standard deviation of 0.036, but I have no idea whether this is the best result I can get. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance!

#### EDIT

After @roman-luštrik's remark, here is my new version of the code. Still horrible, and not so close from optimising the matrix, but slowly getting there!

```
# Data: 30 items (pictures to choose from)

PictureNames <- data.frame(Names = c("wf01", "wf02", "wf03", "wf04", "wf05",
              "wf06", "wf07", "wf08", "wf09", "wf10", "wf11", "wf12", "wf13",
              "wf14", "wf15", "wf16", "wf17", "wf18", "wf19", "wf20", "wf21",
              "wf22", "wf23", "wf24", "wf25", "wf26", "wf27", "wf28", "wf29",
              "wf30"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

set.seed(10)

sample01 <- data.frame(Names = sort(sample(PictureNames$Names[c(4:30)], 15)))
sample02 <- anti_join(PictureNames, sample01)
sample03 <- data.frame(Names = sort(sample(PictureNames$Names[c(1:6, 10:30)], 15)))
sample04 <- anti_join(PictureNames, sample03)
sample05 <- data.frame(Names = sort(sample(PictureNames$Names[c(1:12, 16:30)], 15)))
sample06 <- anti_join(PictureNames, sample05)
sample07 <- data.frame(Names = sort(sample(PictureNames$Names[c(1:18, 22:30)], 15)))
sample08 <- anti_join(PictureNames, sample07)
sample09 <- data.frame(Names = sort(sample(PictureNames$Names[c(1:24, 28:30)], 15)))
sample10 <- anti_join(PictureNames, sample09)

AllSamples <- data.frame(sample01, sample02, sample03, sample04, sample05,
                     sample06, sample07, sample08, sample09, sample10)

colnames(AllSamples) <- c("sA", "sB", "sC", "sD", "sE", "sF", "sG", "sH", "sI", "sJ")

CoOccurMat <- matrix(nrow = length(PictureNames$Names), ncol = length(PictureNames$Names),
                 dimnames = c(PictureNames, PictureNames))

for(j in 1:length(PictureNames$Names)){
  for(i in 1:length(PictureNames$Names)){
CoOccurMat[i,j] <- sum(ifelse(sapply(PictureNames,
                       function(x)colSums(xor(AllSamples == PictureNames$Names[j],
                       AllSamples == PictureNames$Names[i]))) == 2, 1, 0))
ColSd <- apply(CoOccurMat, 2, sd)
OverallSd <- sd(ColSd)
  }
}

CoOccurMat
ColSd
OverallSd
```

Comment: Care to put this algorithm in code and show where you fall short? As it is, you appear to be asking a full implementation in R, which could be deemed as a bit broad for this format.

Comment: I tried to implement the algorithm, up to where I can!